# How to access data in 3 tier MVC5 application using EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created MVC5 three tiered application that uses EF6. I've separated the application into BL (business layer), DL (data layer) and presentation layers. I can successfully implement the BL and DL. However, I couldn't retrieve data from BL and display it on the views.

Here is what I attempted to do:

```
//on the controller    
public ActionResult Index()
{
   TrackerBL t = new TrackerBL(); //BL
   var model = t.GetApps(); //method on my BL that returns a list
   return View(model);
}
```

and here is what I tried on the view

```
@model List<AppTracker.Models.Apps>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>App Tracker</h2>
@foreach(var m in Model)
{
<div>m.Name</div>
}
```

However, it throws the following exception:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AppTracker.BL.AppData]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AppTracker.Models.Apps]'.

Where did I get lost?

Comment: what is the return type of t.GetApps() ?

Comment: It's some property class I've created:
    public class AppData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
     }

Comment: The Model you want to show in the view is different than the one you have in the Index Action. If you change the views' model to @@model List<AppTracker.BL.AppData> it'll work

Answer (score 1):

So its a case of passing the wrong model to the view or referencing the wrong model in the view.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[AppTracker.BL.AppData]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[AppTracker.Models.Apps]'.

The message says that you have passed the below to the view

> System.Collections.Generic.List1[AppTracker.BL.AppData]

But the view, as shown in the code requires

> System.Collections.Generic.List1[AppTracker.Models.Apps]

Thanks

p.s Thought i'd give it an official answer.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `List<AppData>` from Controller to View but the model (you want to show) at the view is diffrent (`List<Apps>`). It makes the problem.

You can only show the model at the view that one you pass from the controller.